# How to remove bitbake layer containing ${BSPDIR}

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to remove some BBLAYERS using `bitbake-layers remove-layer`
There are multiple layers ending with meta-multimedia and I would like to remove only the `meta-xxx/meta-multimedia` I cannot run `bitbake-layers remove-layer` because it removes both layers. Result of bitbake-layers show-layers show:

```
meta-multimedia       /projects/bsp/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia  5
meta-multimedia       /projects/bsp/sources/meta-xxx/meta-multimedia  5
```

Yet in the file bblayers.conf the layers are added as follows:

```
BBLAYERS = " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia "
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-xxx/meta-multimedia"
```

I have tried running below commands + some more:

```
bitbake-layers remove-layer ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-xxx/meta-multimedia
No layers matching /projects/bsp/build/${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-xxx/meta-multimedia found in BBLAYERS

bitbake-layers remove-layer \${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-xxx/meta-multimedia
No layers matching /projects/bsp/build/\${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-xxx/meta-multimedia found in BBLAYERS

bitbake-layers remove-layer /projects/bsp/sources/meta-xxx/meta-multimedia
No layers matching /projects/bsp/sources/meta-xxx/meta-multimedia found in BBLAYERS
```

They all fail.
I could grep -v or remove all meta-multimedia layers and add the one from meta-openembedded but it seems weird that bitbake-layers does not support such a request. Am I am missing something?

The bblayers.conf is created by a layer supporting my HW and I'd like to put my modifications on the top of that layer, so that I can easily upgrade to new version of the HW layer in the future. Any suggestions?

Comment: The name of the layer is determined by the `BBFILE_COLLECTIONS` variable, which is usually extended in the `conf/layer.conf` file of the corresponding layer. Do you have the option to change this value to something unique in meta-xxx?

Comment: It is a meta-layer coming from the HW privider. I can make overwrites in there but I'd prefer keep this layer and do grep  -v or remove both layers and add the one that I wanted to keep. I just found it surprising that I could not find the way with bitbake-layers

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. If there is `/` present in layer name in the name or there `*` is not present in the layer name provided to `bitbake-layers remove-layer`, tool will add absolute path to the layer (which will not work)
solution is:

```
bitbake-layers remove-layer */meta-xxx/meta-multimedia
```

There is unfortunately no documentation that describes that.